# NextJS: Call to static function inside of library states function is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

Inside of a library there's a class called MyClass. MyClass has a static method called setData. The contents of the MyClass.js are as follows:

```
class MyClass {
   static DATA = '';

   static setData(data) {
      MyClass.DATA = data || '';
   }
}
export default MyClass;
```

Inside of a file I call the MyClass as follows

```
import MyClass from 'library/dist/utilities/MyClass';

MyClass.setData('new data');
```

When I try to run

```
next dev
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: _library_dist_utilities_MyClass__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.setData is not a function
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm calling the static method? Is it a problem with webpack?

EDIT: Added the export to the MyClass.

Comment: I figured out why the import was messed up. For some reason all of my imports are coming in as object with a default as a key. If I want to use the component I have to add the default. For my example this would be: MyClass.default.setData('new data'); Once I figure out why this is happening, I'll add an answer with the full details.

Comment: Please show us how you are `export`ing the `MyCLass` from that module. You probably should write `export default class MyClass { … }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my package.json. I had this for the type

```
"type": "module",
```

Once I took this out, the problem went away.